# require a lot of time and energy

Tags: infinitives, complementation, active-vs-passive

a. The bridge will require a lot of time and energy to construct.

b. The bridge will require a lot of time and energy to be constructed.

c. The bridge will need a lot of time and energy to construct.

d. The bridge will need a lot of time and energy to be constructed.

It seems to me that (b) and (d) are grammatical but might sound pretty awkward to native speakers.

Native speakers I asked seemed to find (a) and (c) natural and don't seem to find them incorrect. Yet, I am incapable of parsing them and they look ungrammatical to me.

Consider:

e. This patient needs a lot of money to cure.

Do you find (e) grammatical?

What's your take on the sentences a-d?

Answer (score 2):

The infinitive phrases don't have explict subjects or objects, so these have to be understood from the context. So your first sentence would be understood as

> The bridge will require a lot of time and energy (for people) to construct (the bridge).

A similar reasoning can be applied to (e).  But there is a better way:

> We need a lot of money to cure this patient.

That's better since the patient doesn't need the money, only the doctors (etc) need money. That is easier to understand and probably expresses what you really mean.

As written, (e) is problematic.  While bridges can't construct things, patients can (in principle) cure things, so the reading of the infinitive with patient as the subject is not ruled out. That makes (e) less idiomatic.